# Why are oil drops' charges quantized on a large scale?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons

Recently, I've carried out a Millikan oil drop experiment. It was a tiny experiment I only recorded three droplets. I calculated the 3 charges of the droplets to be approximately $q_1=86.6\ e$, $q_2=181.24\ e$ and $q_3=44.68\ e$.

The issue is that although these charges are larger than the elementary charge by a factor of a hundred, they are still integer multiples of one another:
$\dfrac{q_1}{q_3}=1.94\approx 2$, $\dfrac{q_2}{q_3}=4.06\approx 4$ and $\dfrac{q_2}{q_1}=2.09\approx 2$

Why is it so ?

Comment: Systematic error?